# Shall I use "directive" or "controller" for this case?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We want to write a dialog directive in an angularjs application, but have something hard to decide.

Say I have some buttons on the HTML and we want to write a directive 'popup':

```
<div>
  <button popup>Email</button>
  <button popup>Phone</button>      
  <button popup>Other</button>
</div>
```

When clicked on the button, it will show a popup dialog with something. There are some common UI behaviors between the 3 buttons, as well as some different logic.

### option 1 (no controller)

We define 3 directives, e.g. `popup-email`, `popup-phone`, `popup-other`:

```
app.directive('popup-email', ['user', 'ngDialog', function(user, ngDialog) {
    return {
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if(user.email) {
            ngDialog.open({...});
          } else {
            element.addClass("disabled");
          }
       }
    }
}]);

app.directive('popup-phone', ['user', 'ngDialog', function(user, ngDialog) {
    return {
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if(user.phone) {
            ngDialog.open({...});
          } else {
            element.addClass("disabled");
          }
       }
    }
}]);

app.directive('popup-other', ['user', 'ngDialog', function(user, ngDialog) {
    return {
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if(user.other) {
            ngDialog.open({...});
          } else {
            element.addClass("disabled");
          }
       }
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <button popup-email>Email</button>
  <button popup-email>Phone</button>      
  <button popup-email>Other</button>
</div>
```

In this option, we will define 3 directives, no controller. The good part is each button is a standalone button with the directive, all the logic is inside the directive. The bad part is we have some business logic in each directive, and there are some common logic in all the 3 directives.

### Option 2 (with a controller)

We will provide only one directive for the command behavior, and one controller for the difference:

```
app.directive('popup', ['ngDialog', function(ngDialog) {
    return {
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if(attrs.enable==="true") {
            ngDialog.open({...});
          } else {
            element.addClass("disabled");
          }
       }
    }
}]);

app.controler('ContactController', function(scope, user) {
    scope.enableEmail = if(user.email) true else false;
    scope.enablePhone = if(user.phone) true else false;
    scope.enableOther = if(user.other) true else false;
});
```

The HTML will be:

```
<div>
  <button popup enable="{{enableEmail}}">Email</button>
  <button popup enable="{{enablePhone}}">Phone</button>      
  <button popup enable="{{enableOther}}">Other</button>
</div>
```

For this option, the good part is the directive is reusable, but we will have to define a controller for them.

Comment: Do you want to reuse these buttons on multiple views ?

Comment: Yes, this directive may be used on more views

Comment: I'm trying something on jsfiddle. Thinking of 2 directives communicating with each other, but not sure yet.

Comment: not worthy of a full answer but Angular is moving away from controllers in Dart which will certainly impact the unified codebase that they are shooting for in 2.0  - In short - Use a directive http://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html

Comment: I should have added that business logic should be shunted off to the services.  In general, reusable business logic should never reside in controllers or directives.

Comment: In this demo, the business logic is not reusable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second option is wrong, its strange to pass user both to directive and controller. Also if you have it in controller I would pass it to view and determine "enable" attribute there.

But when I speak about passing "user" into directive as dependency. I am not sure if you really want to do that, Id rather pass data to directive using attribute, but i don't know your exact use case, so its up to you.

If you insist on passing user that way I would suggest more clever directive, which accept field on which is enabled.

```
<button popup="email">Email</button>
```

When using isolated scope on attribute directive, you can use that attribute also for passing string value with field name, so you can get your field and then determine what to do using

```
app.directive('popup', function (..) {
...
return {
   restrict : "A",
   scope : {
     field-name : "@popup"
   },
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      ...
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the option 2, the `user` actually is not need, the directive `popup` is a generic directive no related to any business models like `user`

Comment: in that case i would simply use standard ng-disabled directive and pass !user.email. And if only thing it should do its generic popup without more informatin needed then I would do

    <button popup ng-disabled="!user.email">Email</button>

Comment: We have some special behavior for "disabled" popup, i.e. add a special css class to the tag, so I can't simply use `ng-disabled`

Comment: ok, but still if you make your own attribute for this, you should use it like own_disable="!user.email" and not pass boolean from controller.

Comment: So you don't want to put the logic into a controller, but what if the logic is much more complex, e.g. `user.email.startWith("test") || user.email.length < 10 || user.email.endsWith("test.com") || user.email.contains("good")`?

Comment: No I just said is strange send those kind of boolean variable even, at least you can just use "user.email" as boolean value. The previous situation was really just about show/not show, so i would check it in tempalte. In the case of more complex I would put that conditions to the separate service/directive. You can have one directive for popup and other one for determine your complex condition. it would then look like.

     `<button popup eneble-user-phone="user"></button>`

I am sorry, but I cant probably help you more, because i don't understand what exactly you want to achieve.